# Python Multiprocessing Executing Function on Many Files

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list of csv files that contain numbers, all the same size. I also have lists of data associated with each file (e.g. list of dates,  list of authors of each). What I'm trying to do is read in the file, perform a function , then put the maximum value with its value, along with the data associated with it, into a dataframe.

I have approximately 100,000 files to compute, so being able to use multiprocessing would save an incredible amount of time. Important to note: I'm running the following code in Jupyter Notebook on windows, which I know has known issues with multiprocessing. The code I've tried so far is:

```
import needed things

files = [file1, file2,...,fileN]
dates = [date1, ... , dateN]
authors = [author1, ... , authorN]

def func(file):
    #Reads in file, computes func on values
    index = files.index(file)
    d1 = {'Filename': file, 'Max': max, 'X-value': x-values, 'Date': dates[index], 'Author': authors[index]}
    return d1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
    data = pool.map(FindTriggers, files)
    summaryDF = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This runs indefinitely, a known issue, but I'm not sure what the error is or how to fix it. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Why don't you just run it normally?

Comment: Between the missing imports, the wrong indentation, the use of globals between code that is supposed to run on separate processes and the somewhat pointless logic, it's hard to point out anything that wouldn't cause problems. You should share some code that you think should actually do what you want it to do, and that runs, and then focus on a single problem you have with it.

Comment: By the way, if most of what you're doing is reading files (the logic seems fairly trivial), then the overhead of the extra processes and the fact that all of them are trying to do I/O on the same storage is more likely to slow things down than speed them up - please make clear what exactly you're looking to do with the contents of these files and how you're reading them.